# How to set up the browser scrollbar to scroll part of a page? (higher than footer part hidden)   just like http://i-donline.com/

Tags: html, css

How to set up the browser scrollbar to scroll part of a page? (higher than footer part hidden)   just like http://i-donline.com/

http://jsfiddle.net/hVvfn/2/

```
.header{
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 1000px;
height: 100px;
background:  blue;
z-index: 1;
}
.contentwrap{
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 100px;
width: 1000px;
height: 250px;
background:  ;
}
.footer{
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 350px;
width: 1000px;
height: 300px;
background:  blue;
}
.row{
position: relative;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 800px;
height: 250px;
border: purple 1px solid;
background: gray;
}​
```

Comment: i found [how-to-set-up-the-browser-scrollbar-to-scroll-part-of-a-page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83225/how-to-set-up-the-browser-scrollbar-to-scroll-part-of-a-page?rq=1) and [scroll-particular-div-contents-with-browsers-main-scrollbar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887112/scroll-particular-div-contents-with-browsers-main-scrollbar)  both not set with footer..

Comment: this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/c3eAa/) hidden the wrap overflow, will be close what i want  but the browser scrollbar distance is too long...

Answer (score 0):

There is a library called as iScroll. Used just for these kind of things. You can check it out I think it will help. In fact I have used it many times. Works like charm. Here is the link:

[**iScroll here**](http://cubiq.org/iscroll)

Comment: Thanks, but i want to know is website still use the browser scrollbar

Comment: you can configure it in that way.

Comment: i check the iscroll horizontal demo ,but if pull the window size the content scroll bar will show and flash?